# Google chart, formatted dynamic h-axis is not working

Tags: charts

[Graph image link which is generated when hardcoding in h-axis ticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3xuY.png)

I have to draw a line chart where I have to apply x-axis ticks dynamically.
Columns in chart are as follows:

```
  data.addColumn('number', 'Equity'); // x-axis ticks 
  data.addColumn('number', 'A');  //series one
  data.addColumn('number', 'B');  //series two
```

I am adding data in rows is like given below, there can be multiple rows
which is known only at run time. So I have to insert all the rows 
dynamically.

```
   data.addRow([2, 0.8, null]);
   data.addRow([3, null, 5]);   
   .........
   .........
```

I have to format the h-axis ticks So When I am hardcoding h-axis as below 
then all the ticks are appearing:

```
hAxis: {
     gridlines: {color: '#fff'},        
     ticks: [
             {v:0, f: ''},
             {v:1, f: 'Equity#1'},
         {v:2, f: 'Equity#2'},
         {v:3, f: 'Equity#3'},
         {v:4, f: 'Funds Investment Value'}
           ]
   }
```

But When I am assigning a array to h-axis ticks, then ticks are not 
appearing.

hAxis: {
          gridlines: {color: '#fff'},
          ticks: hAxisTicksArray
       },

The array is having the same values as I did in hardcoding. Just for your 
reference I am inserting values in array as given below:

```
   var hAxisTicksArray = [];
   hAxisTicksArray.push("{v:1, f: 'Equity#1'}");
   hAxisTicksArray.push("{v:2, f: 'Equity#2'}");
   ........
   ........

   hAxisTicksArray::
   {v:1, f: 'Equity#1'},
   {v:2, f: 'Equity#2'},
   {v:3, f: 'Equity#3'},
   {v:4, f: 'Funds Investment Value'}
```

Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like its coming along nicely, well done...

Comment: @WhiteHat : Thanks a lot.  You provided great help to achieve this. but annotation text are overlapping when, points are very close to each other. Also to see the tool-tip , I have to move mouse very slowley around the points, and the tool tip is not coming when I am hovering mouse exactly at the point, its coming when mouse is little far from the point. Can you please see the fiddle and provide me help:  https://jsfiddle.net/sainirohit77/5xb68cfw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the hover problem is due to the negative `stem`

try removing...

```
annotations: {
  stem: {
    length: -5
  }
},
```

and adjusting the `'y'`, along with `'x'`

(not sure why `'23x'` doesn't adjust properly)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawVisualization();
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawVisualization, false);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'PC');
  data.addColumn('number', 'A');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

  data.addColumn('number', 'B');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

  data.addColumn('number', 'C');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
  data.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});

  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 0.8, '0.8x', 'PC#1, Low, 0.8x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: square; fill-color: #DB1D40; }'
  ,null,null,null, null,null,null,null,null]);

  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 7.4, '7.4x', 'PC#1, High, 7.4x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: square; fill-color: #DB1D40; }',
  null,null,null, null,null,null,null,null]);

  data.addRow([{v: 2, f: ''}, 12.2, '12.2x', 'PC#1, Multiple, 12.2x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: triangle; fill-color: #DB1D40; }',
  null,null,null, null,null,null,null,null]);


  data.addRow([{v: 3, f: ''},  null,null,null,null,
   5, '5.0x', 'PC#2, Low, 5.0x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: square; fill-color: #DB1D40; }',
  null,null,null,null]);

  data.addRow([{v: 3, f: ''}, null,null,null,null,
  15, '15x', 'PC#2, High, 15x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: square; fill-color: #DB1D40; }',
  null,null,null,null]);

  data.addRow([{v: 3, f: ''},  null,null,null,null,
  23, '23x', 'PC#2, Multiple, 23x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: triangle; fill-color: #DB1D40;}',
  null,null,null,null]);



  data.addRow([{v: 1, f: ''},  null,null,null, null,null,null,null,null,
   2, '2.0x', 'PC#2, Low, 2.0x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: square; fill-color: #DB1D40; }']);

  data.addRow([{v: 1, f: ''},  null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
  7, '7x', 'PC#2, High, 7x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: square; fill-color: #DB1D40; }']);

  data.addRow([{v: 1, f: ''},  null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
  11, '11x', 'PC#2, Multiple, 11x',
  'point { size: 5; shape-type: triangle; fill-color: #DB1D40;}']);


  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);

  var annotations = {};
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (text, index) {
      if (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
         annotations[index] = {};
         if(!text.innerHTML.startsWith("PC")) {
           annotations[index].x = parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x')) + 20;
         } else {
           annotations[index].x = parseFloat(text.getAttribute('x'));
         }
         annotations[index].y = parseFloat(text.getAttribute('y')) + 18;
      }
    });

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (text, index) {
        if (text.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
          text.setAttribute('x', annotations[index].x);
          text.setAttribute('y', annotations[index].y);
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    legend: 'none',
    colors: ['GREY'],
    seriesType : 'bars',
    series : {
      0 : {
        type : 'line',
        targetAxisIndex : 0,
        lineDashStyle: [3, 3]

      },
      1 : {
        type : 'line',
        targetAxisIndex : 0,
        lineDashStyle: [6, 3]
      },
      2 : {
        type : 'line',
        targetAxisIndex : 0,
        lineDashStyle: [6, 3]
      }
    },
    hAxis: {
      gridlines: {color: '#fff'},
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: 'PC#0'},
        {v: 1, f: 'PC#1'},
        {v: 2, f: 'PC#2'},
        {v: 3, f: 'PC#3'},
        {v: 4, f: '4'}
      ]
    },
    pointSize: 5,
    dataOpacity: 1.0,
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Its working. Your question (not sure why '23x' doesn't adjust properly), is because graph height is just 24. This text is not getting enough space to be written at correct location so it is little bit downwards. I have changed 23 to 18 and now its looking correct. Also I have made stem length to zero to remove the small vertical stem line at all the top points. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
I caught the issue. I was inserting the data in h-axis ticks array as string
instead of putting that as json object. Now its working fine.

 Below is the wrong way, I was doing:
 hAxisTicksArray.push("{v:"+hAxisTick+", f: '"+firstColValue+"'}");

Below is the correct way, which I am doing right now and h-axis ticks are
coming properly:
 hAxisTicksArray.push({v:hAxisTick, f: firstColValue});
```